# Unable to send sms on whatapp throguht route

Tags: python

bascially i am making a route in which i have connect my api of whatapp when i send a number in my json response thought software this route should send me a whatapp message on that number

```
@app.route('/v1.1/userRegistor', methods=['POST','GET'])
def get_user():
    data = request.get_json()
    numbers=data['numbers']
    api_url = ('https://app.simplywhatsapp.com/api/send.php?number=numbers&type=text&message=test%20message&instance_id=634CF8BECCB26&access_token=78495efca3672167f9ed88cb93acd2e1')
    r = requests.get(api_url)
    return r.json()
```

this is my request body:
{

```
"numbers":"923142985338"
```

}

Comment: what is the type of data here, str or dict? also, check what is the result of print(r) . Another thing you can do is to use format method here as the URL wont recognize numbers as a variable

Comment: Remarkably similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74094034/unable-to-connect-api-with-my-route-in-python-flask#comment130821527_74094034 from just 1 hour earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't formatting your API request URL. The variables can't be passed directly in the string, as they can't be distinguished from words. You need to use a format string.

```
api_url = f'https://app.simplywhatsapp.com/api/send.php?number={numbers}&type={text}&message=test%20message&instance_id=634CF8BECCB26&access_token=78495efca3672167f9ed88cb93acd2e1'
```

Read more about it here: https://www.pythoncheatsheet.org/cheatsheet/string-formatting